# Yii2 How to auto register new user without using site/signup

Tags: yii2, save, yii2-advanced-app, autosave

I want to signup new user every time I add a new client. I do not want to manually register a new user using the web/site/signup form via the browser.
I am trying to auto register new users from ClientController and I am having no luck at all. No error returned, it is as if the code doesn't run at all.
I can easily register the same user through site controller at site/signup but can not at all auto register through another controller by calling SignupForm model. Please help 
I have this in my client controller

```
namespace frontend\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use frontend\models\Client;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
public function actionCreate()
    {
       $model = new Client;
       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
         {
           $model->save();
           $useremail = $model->Email;

           $signupForm = new SignupForm();
           $signupForm->username = $useremail;
           $signupForm->password = $useremail;
           $signupForm->email = $useremail;
           $signupForm->created_at = time();
           $signupForm->picture = null;
           $signupForm->created_by = Yii::$app->session->get('USER_ID');
           $NewUser = $signupForm->signup();
           print_r($NewUser);
                        exit;


        }
    else{
           return $this->render('create', [
                                  'model' => $model
                               ]);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my SignupForm code:

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;
use common\models\User;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;
/**
* Signup form
*/
class SignupForm extends Model
{
public $username;
public $email;
public $password;
public $picture;
public $created_by;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */

public function rules()
{
    return [
                ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
                ['username', 'required'],
                ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
                ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

                ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
                ['email', 'required'],
                ['email', 'email'],
                ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

                ['password', 'required'],
                ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
                [['picture'], 'string'],
                [['picture'],'default', 'value'=>null],
                [['created_by'], 'integer'],
                [['created_by'], 'default', 'value'=>Yii::$app->session->get('USER_ID')],
            ];
}


/**
 * Signs user up.
 *
 * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
 */
public function signup()
{

    $this->created_by = Yii::$app->session->get('USER_ID');
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();

        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->created_by = $this->created_by;
        $user->picture = $this->picture;
        //Save user
        $user->save(false);
        return $user;
    }

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Check User model for errors after saving with some debug statement.

Comment: You controller code is not clear try add  the complete action/function for the related  part

Comment: @karpy It passes the validation and no errors returned. Nothing get returned, it does not even run anything under the line $signupForm->signup();

Comment: @ scaisEdge  I have edited as requested

Comment: print_r($NewUser); is never reached but, if I add new client using the browser at web/site/signup, it saves new user correctly using the same SignupForm code.

Comment: Check your SignupForm.signup function for errors after doing validation... vardump ($this->errors)

Comment: I figured out what caused errors not being shown. Somehow firebug was frozen and was not reporting anything. I restarted my machine and everything is working. There were a couple of errors unrelated to this piece of code that were preventing it to run and was not being shown by firebug because it was frozen. The code should run as is with no issues. Thank you everyone for your kind help.